# Can Jackson (JSON library) autogenerate POJO for deserialization?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'm using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in a Spring application to deserialize JSON streams (coming from REST services) into POJOs. 
At the moment I use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) web utility to generate the POJO from the JSON stream. 
The point is that in the future I will handle different JSON streams and I think it will become more and more complex and frustrating to generate POJOs for the different JSON streams.

Is there any way to let the project auto-generate the POJO starting from the JSON stream? For example the [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) library provides a Maven plugin to generate the Q* classes used for query building. 
Does it exist a similar plugin for Jackson or any other way to make things done?

Thank you in previous

Giulio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jackson [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) makes no mention of anything similar and I have never heard of anything like what you mention.

You mentioned QueryDSL which generates the Q* classes during the build phase. That means that you are willing take use extra steps to build your code, which means that you should't have any troubles using *jsonschema2pojo*'s  [Maven](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#wiki-the-maven-plugin) or [Gradle](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-jsonschema2pojo-plugin) plugins

Comment: Yeah, I've just found it reading the bottom of the jsonschema2pojo page.
I have edited the plugin configuration according to the parameters documented here (http://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/0.4.1/generate-mojo.html). Important: if you want to convert a JSON (not a JSON Schema) into a POJO you have to set the sourceType parameter of the jsonschema2pojo Maven plugin to "json".

Comment: @gvdm Good obsvervation!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with your REST design.
REST endpoints should be very specific. 
Each rest endpoint should represent a resource, 
in other words, a domain/pojo that usually represents an entity of your data base.

If your endpoint receive more than one resource representation, you could end up
with a huge DTO, very hard to maintain.

Usually, you build your domain model. These domains are regular pojos, so you would
use them to convert json/java - java/json.
This should scale well. Any modification to your model should affect your json stream as well.
If you modify a domain, only the endpoint that represents this resource will take effect.

Comment: Hi @raonicoelho.
The point is that I'm calling some REST services thaht I didn't develope, so I don't have its generator model. Therefore I need to build the POJOs from the JSON